# CosmosDB partion key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Below is the cosmos document db object representing candidate profile object for job positions. The object formation is still in initial phase with minimum of attributes given. Based on data object below i am thinking of using multiple attributes like name, location etc for partition. Appreciate your guidance / inputs in picking a partition key. The object has potential to grow big with more data but for now this is what we are planning to implement in phase 1

```
{
"Guid": "7ce84d91-7bf3-4b98-a945-108464cc6282",
"Name": {
    "FirstName": "Manu",
    "LastName": "San Martin",
    "PreferredName": "Juan",
    "MiddleNameInitial": "M",
    "MiddleName": "Manuel"
},
"Location": {
    "Country": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "US"
    },
    "Address1": "Bv Chacabuco 421",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "new york",
    "State": "new york",
    "Zip": "10001"
},
"Contact": {
    "EmailAddress": "qa@wawaqsa.com",
    "EmailOptOut": "qa@wawawaqa.com",
    "PhoneNumber": "1253647851",
    "PhoneType": "Mobile"
},
"Opportunity": {
    "InterestLevel": "string",
    "Elegibility": "string"
},
"Enabled": true,
"AvailableDate": "2019-08-17T00:00:00",
"Skills": null,
"Preferences": null,
"SocialMediaHandles": null,
"id": "0f3277f2-5b73-4dfb-b31b-df65bcb8d20b",
"DeletedAt": null,
"IsLatest": true,
```

}

Comment: The problem is that it depends on your use cases. If your app is very write-heavy, then priority could be a partition key that causes writes to spread across partitions evenly. If the app is read-heavy, then you want to try to ensure that most common queries can query a single partition, and not do cross-partition queries.

Comment: Are you giving each application a unique GUID or do you want to use another number? Why are GUID and ID different?  Should opportunity be an array?  An person may be applying for multiple jobs so you want to link the jobs with the person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cosmos db, we should consider choosing a partition key that has a wide range of values and access patterns that are evenly spread across logical partitions. This helps spread the data and the activity in your container across the set of logical partitions.

Your choice of partition key should balance the need for efficient partition queries and transactions against the goal of distributing items across multiple partitions to achieve scalability. Candidates for partition keys might include properties that appear frequently as a filter in your queries. Queries can be efficiently routed by including the partition key in the filter predicate.

For you,i presume that location or name is the most common query condition, you could consider pick them as the pk. The most important thing is to combine your own business development needs.

BTW, the choice of PK is of great significance. Once selected, modification or deletion will not be supported later in cosmos db.